# jQuery add href to string

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to add an attribute (href) into a td of a table.

I guess jQuery would work!

I need help please...

url: `http://mysite`

The original table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Url</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='Collection'>
            <td>Collection</td>
            <td>Collection1</td>
            <td>/Collection1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='Site'>
            <td>Site</td>
            <td>Site1</td>
            <td>/site1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So the result would be :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Url</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='Collection'>
            <td>Collection</td>
            <td>Collection1</td>
            <td><a href="http://mysite/Collection1">/Collection1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='Site'>
            <td>Site</td>
            <td>Site1</td>
            <td><a href="http://mysite/site1">/site1</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: td doesn't have href attribute.

Comment: i tried that $("td:eq(2)").each(function() {
$('<a href="http://sp-dev""></a>').appendTo('td')
But it didn't work

Comment: you should append to $(this) since .each loops thought list of tds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant "add a link into a `td` of a table", try this:

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var cell = $('td:last', this),
        url  = $(cell).text();

    $(cell).wrapInner('<a href="' + url + '">');
})​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4hMey/1/

Comment: You want `wrapInner`, not `wrap` here since `wrap` will make the `a` tag the parent and the `td` tag the child.

Comment: @amurra Good call! Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

give the td you want to change a class so you can select them easily with jQuery, then change the html contents.

```
<td class="MYCLASS"><a href="http://mysite/site1">/site1</a></td>


$('.MYCLASS').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<a href="http://mysite' + text + '">' + text + '</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always know that the last td will need the link then you can do something like this:

```
var urlTd = $('table tbody td:last-child');
urlTd.wrapInner('<a href="http://mysite' + urlTd.html() + '" />');
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHLS3/) showing it working.